# The functor from $sl_2-mod$ to $U_q(sl_2)-mod$.

Tags: modules, representation-theory, quantum-groups

Let $sl_2-mod$ be the category of all finite dimensional $sl_2$-modules and let $U_q(sl_2)-mod$ be the category of all finite dimensional $U_q(sl_2)$-modules, $q$ is not a root of unity. It is said that $sl_2-mod$ is equivalent to $U_q(sl_2)-mod$. What is the functor from $sl_2-mod$ to $U_q(sl_2)-mod$ and what is the functor from $U_q(sl_2)-mod$ to $sl_2-mod$? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a much weaker statement than it appears: both categories are semisimple so this more or less says that they have the same number of simple objects, which is countably infinite. There are stronger things you can say, namely you can match up dimensions, weights, and tensor product decompositions (although you don't get a monoidal functor).